# Erro na adição de chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Estou com problemas na criação de uma chave estrangeira. Estou fazendo o projeto no MySQL Workbench. O script SQL gerado é o seguinte:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comercio`.`cliente` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comercio`.`cliente` (
    `cliente_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cpf` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `nome` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `rg` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `sexo` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `nascimento` DATE NOT NULL,
    `telefone` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`cliente_id`, `cpf`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comercio`.`endereco` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comercio`.`endereco` (
    `endereco_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cidade` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `estado` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `rua` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `bairro` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `numero` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `cep` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `complemento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `cpf_cliente` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`endereco_id`),
    INDEX `FK_CPF_CLIENTE_idx` (`cpf_cliente` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CPF_CLIENTE`
        FOREIGN KEY (`cpf_cliente`)
        REFERENCES `comercio`.`cliente` (`cpf`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

O erro informado é o seguinte:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comercio`.`endereco` (
          `endereco_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `cidade` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `estado` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `rua` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `bairro` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `numero` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `cep` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `complemento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `cpf_cliente` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`endereco_id`),
          INDEX `FK_CPF_CLIENTE_idx` (`cpf_cliente` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_CPF_CLIENTE`
            FOREIGN KEY (`cpf_cliente`)
            REFERENCES `comercio`.`cliente` (`cpf`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo [a seção sobre chave estrangeira](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) na documentação do MySQL:

> InnoDB permite uma chave estrangeira referenciar qualquer coluna ou grupo de colunas. Entretanto, na tabela referenciada, deve haver um index onde as coluna referenciadas são listadas como as primeiras colunas na mesma ordem.

Ou seja, no seu caso, como a coluna `cpf` aparece como a segunda coluna declarada na sua `PRIMARY KEY`, você deve criar um outro index para ele, exemplo:

```
 INDEX `CPF_idx` (`cpf` ASC)
```

Seu script inteiro ficaria assim:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cliente` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente` (
    `cliente_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cpf` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `nome` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `rg` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `sexo` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `nascimento` DATE NOT NULL,
    `telefone` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`cliente_id`, `cpf`),
     INDEX `CPF_idx` (`cpf` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `endereco` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `endereco` (
    `endereco_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cidade` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `estado` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `rua` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `bairro` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `numero` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `cep` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `complemento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `cpf_cliente` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`endereco_id`),
    INDEX `FK_CPF_CLIENTE_idx` (`cpf_cliente` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CPF_CLIENTE`
        FOREIGN KEY (`cpf_cliente`)
        REFERENCES `cliente` (`cpf`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```